# SSIS Package Execution from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis

why when i execute my ssis package in visual studio 2013 for the second time, i get a problem in my OLE DB Destination telling me that i already have those data in my sql server. so what should i do !! i want, when i execute it for the second time, my ssis to recognize my data and don't cause a problem and execute it normally. [image: this is my ssis package]
[image: this is my sql data]

Comment: Well, you've set up the table so you can't insert the same data twice. you can either clear it out before the load, or include a lookup in the flow to match against the data that exists, so you then only insert that data that doesn't exist.

Comment: i didn't know how to use it ! (the lookup task)

Comment: Cool, hopefully that's a pointer in the right direction- there will be plenty of tutorials online for how to use the lookup task.

Comment: okay thank you, i just new in data warehouse and my final project is about it

Comment: @SirinàStrong: Can you tell use what are the columns in your sources? How are you creating Title_Id? Do you want update your destination if the Title_Id is duplicate? Do you want delete the row in your destination if there are not exist in your source for second time? Give use the answer of these question after that we can give you a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I suggest you to create a TRSF table like below code :

```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.TRFS_TD_Titles
   (
    Title_ID varchar(50),
    Title varchar(500),
    [Type] varchar(500)
   )
```

Then in your package at first iin your `ControlFlow` You should run a command for clearing all records in this table before your `DataFlow task`.

You need to add a `Execute SQL Task` before your `DataFlow task` in your `ControlFlow`.

And then Run this command by your `Execute SQL Task`:

```
Truncate Table dbo.TRFS_TD_Titles
```

Then in your `DataFlow` you need just to change the destination table in your last component (OLE DB Destination)(in your package it named TD Title). you have to transfer all rows to `dbo.TRFS_TD_Titles`.

Then in your `ControlFlow`, Add a second `Execute SQL Task` After your `DataFlow`  and run this command:

```
   MERGE dbo.TD_Titles AS T
   USING dbo.TRFS_TD_Titles AS S
    ON  T.Title_ID = S.Title_ID
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
      SET 
        T.Title = S.Title, 
        T.Type = S.type
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT 
      (Title_ID,Title,[Type])   
    VALUES
      (S.Title_ID,S.Title,S.[Type])
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN  
    DELETE
    ;
```

If you don't need to delete record from your target Table (dbo.TD_Titles), You should just run this command in your second `Execute SQL Task` :

```
MERGE dbo.TD_Titles AS T
USING dbo.TRFS_TD_Titles AS S
 ON  T.Title_ID = S.Title_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE 
   SET 
     T.Title = S.Title, 
     T.Type = S.type
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
 INSERT 
   (Title_ID,Title,[Type])   
 VALUES
   (S.Title_ID,S.Title,S.[Type]);
```

And if you don't need to update existing rows in your destination (dbo.TD_Titles) you need just run this command in your second `Execute SQL Task`:

```
   MERGE dbo.TD_Titles AS T
   USING dbo.TRFS_TD_Titles AS S
    ON  T.Title_ID = S.Title_ID
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT 
      (Title_ID,Title,[Type])   
    VALUES
      (S.Title_ID,S.Title,S.[Type]);
```

You will have one ControlFlow like this image :

[image]